# How do I convert this value 1.2851048260000018E7 (double) to int datatype in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, hiveql

When I run a SQL query, I get a big exponential value 1.2851048260000018E7 for the dollar amount. How to convert it to regular value?

Comment: double - dollar amount. Storing money as inexact data type could lead to rounding errors

Comment: Convert to a decimal/numeric.  You should probably be storing dollar amounts using fixed point numbers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not really looking for `int`, but rather a non-scientific notation. If you simply want dollars and cents use the following (since you didn't provide sample code/data, you'll have to adjust this for your query):

```
SELECT CAST(1.2851048260000018E7 AS decimal(18,2))
```

If you need more decimal digits for calculations, use whatever would be appropriate for scale with the syntax `decimal(precision, scale)`, described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-decimal).

If you really are looking for an `int` datatype, that is dollars with cents rounded, use:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(1.2851048260000018E7, 0) AS int)
```

Use caution if leaving out the `ROUND` function. When you `CAST` a `decimal` to `int`, the number will be truncated at the decimal point, not rounded.